# Unable to update angular version

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, angular, typescript

I am trying to upgrade my angular application. The version of my angular application is 4.2.4 for Basic Apps. 
I am using the steps given in [Angular Update Guide](https://update.angular.io/#4.2:8.0).

As per the guide I have to run the following

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
npm install @angular/cli
ng update @angular/cli
```

But when I tried executing the command

```
ng update @angular/cli
```

it gives me an error saying

```
Error: Cannot update safely because packages have conflicting dependencies. Package @angular/core would need to match both versions "7.2.15" and "8.2.7, which are not compatible.
Cannot update safely because packages have conflicting dependencies. Package @angular/core would need to match both versions "7.2.15" and "8.2.7, which are not compatible.
```

this is what my package.json looks like

```
{
  "name": "stellar",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "ng2-archwizard": "^2.1.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ng2-toastr": "^4.1.2",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.5",
    "npm": "^6.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/c3": "^0.6.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "c3": "^0.6.2",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "^2.0.5",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

Can somebody help to get this sorted

Comment: Try to upgrade core package first

Comment: try to run ng update --force

Comment: @federico scamuzzi I am done with upgrading the version but got caught with this now
`ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/bundles/ngx-bootstrap.es2015.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject' in 'C:\Sameer\Angular Template\DPAngular 8\node_modules\ngx-bootstrap\bundles'` thanks

Comment: @federico scamuzzi I got it sorted added "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3"
But now getting something like
`C:/Sameer/Angular Template/DP Angular 8/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'AnimationTransitionEvent'.`

Comment: @mxr7350 I got it sorted added "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3" But now getting something like C:/Sameer/Angular Template/DP Angular 8/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'AnimationTransitionEvent'.

Comment: @federico scamuzzi Done ng2-toastr removed and added ngx-toastr

Comment: @mxr7350 added rxjs-compat with rxjs 6.0.0 resolved my issue. Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow this [tutorial](https://www.freakyjolly.com/how-to-update-local-angular-cli-version/) or run the commands below:

```js
#Install npm-check-updates
$ npm i -g npm-check-updates
 
#Run npm-check-updates with -u, will upgrade package.json
$ ncu -u
 
#Install updated packages
$ npm install

#Then run
npm install typescript@3.5.3
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you can follow this [tutorial](https://update.angular.io/#4.2:8.0)

Or update your angular package manually the version something like this

```
"@angular/core": "~8.2.4"
```

Update your tsconfig.json like this

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext", // add this line
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",// add this line
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Update:

Install rxjs-compact solve the problem

Comment: I am using the same [Tutorial](https://update.angular.io/#4.2:8.0).
As you said i will try by manually updating individual packages. @Tony Ngo Thanks!!!

Comment: I have manually updated all the relevant packages
When I run the application its giving an error saying
`An unhandled exception occurred: error TS6046: Argument for '--module' option must be: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es6', 'es2015'.
`

Comment: Updated the way you said but no change.
But now I just updated the my typescript from "typescript": "~2.3.3" to  "typescript": "^3.5.1" and got rid of the above error. 
But now caught in a serious problem
`ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/bundles/ngx-bootstrap.es2015.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject' in 'C:\Sameer\Angular Template\DPAngular 8\node_modules\ngx-bootstrap\bundles'`

Comment: I got it sorted added "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3"
But now getting something like
`C:/Sameer/Angular Template/DP Angular 8/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'AnimationTransitionEvent'.`